# how to get the value of my select menu inside another component, from the component the menu is defined in?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a component for a select menu and I couldn't figure out how I can access the value from my select menu when a button is clicked inside another component. Right now the code does not look much but I have created separate components as the code will expand as I work through development.

So when the button is clicked inside Replay component I want to be able to access both the values of my Select menus which are currently selected from the Menu component. I am not entirely sure how to go about doing this?

SelectMenu component:

```
import React, {useContext} from 'react';
import { GlobalContext } from "./Store";




function Menu() {

    const [dataSet] = useContext(GlobalContext);

      const createOptions =
       
        dataSet.map((data) => {
          return <option value={data}>{data.name}</option>
        })

    return (
    <div className="data-list-container">
      <select 
      className="data-select"
      defaultValue={[]}
      >
        {createOptions} 
      </select>
    </div>
    );
}

export default Menu;
```

Component I want to access the selected value when button is clicked:

```
    import React from 'react';
    import Menu from './Menu';
    
    
    
    function Replay() {
    
    
        return (
            <div className='top-container'>
<button>Get Both Selected Values</button>
                <div className='live-replay-container'>
                    <Menu/>
                    <Menu/>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
    
    export default Replay;
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to create two function like

```
const getFirstValue = (val) => {
  // store value in state ex setFirstValue(val)
}

const getSecondValue = (val) => {
  // store value in state ex setSecondValue(val)
}
```

pass this function as props to the menu Component

```
<Menu getValue={getFirstValue}/>
<Menu getValue={getSecondValue}/>
```

and in Menu Component call this function when the value is changed

```
const  MenuChaneg = (e) => {
    props.getValue(e.target.value);
}
```

that way you will get value in the Replay component's state and you can use it however you want

Comment: it appears that its reads value as [object Object]?

Comment: can you elaborate on what you are saying?

Comment: the value which gets set is returned as `[object Object]`

Comment: type of value will be the type of value in  e.target.value