# cant properly display value from select menu

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component which is a select menu and I get the value selected from the select menu when it changes and then both values from the 2 select menus when I click the button but the value appears as [object Object] from the console and then I attached a screenshot of the alert output.

Can anyone see why from my code the values are not as expected in my Replay component as the values display properly on the actually menu it just doesn't seem to be the correct value in the Replay component?

screenshot of alert:

[image]

First component which renders the 2 select menus and button:

```
function Replay() {

    const [firstActivity, setFirstActivity] = useState(); 
    const [secondActivity, setSecondActivity] = useState(); 


    const handleFirstChange = (value) => {
        console.log("evt.target = ",(value));
        setFirstActivity(value.name);
    }

    const handleSecondChange = (value) => {
        setSecondActivity(value.name);
    }


    const handleClick = () => {
        alert("values select are: ", firstActivity, secondActivity);
    }

    return (
        <div className='top-container'>
            <button onClick={handleClick}>Get select values!</button>
            <div className='container'>
                <Menu
                onChange={handleFirstChange}
                />
                <Menu
                onChange={handleSecondChange}
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Replay;
```

2nd select menu component:

```
   import React, {useState, useContext} from 'react';
    import { GlobalContext } from "./Store";
    
    
    
    
    function Menu(props) {
    
        const [activities] = useContext(GlobalContext);
       
        
          const handleMenuChange = (evt) => {
            console.log("evt.target.value = ", evt.target.value);
            props.onChange(evt.target.value);
          }
    
                const createOptions =
      
        
          <>           
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
          </>
    
    
        return (
        <div className="container">
          <select 
          className="select"
          defaultValue="1"

          onChange={handleMenuChange}
          >
            {createOptions} 
          </select>
        </div>
        );
    }
    
    export default Menu;
```

Comment: `alert` doesn't take multiple arguments like `console.log` does.  (One of the many reasons to prefer `console.log` over `alert` for debugging.)  When you use `console.log` instead, what is the result?

Comment: @David that was included in the question it results in [object Object]

Comment: What specific `console.log` operation produced that output?  You may have *alluded* to this information in the question, but when debugging it's important to be specific.

Comment: @David although it appears my states are undefined when console logged?

Comment: @David sorry the onChange function results in object Object being logged when logging the states from the button it results in undefined for firstActivity and  undefined for secondActivity

Comment: Do you mean the `handleFirstChange` function?  So this statement?: `console.log("evt.target = ",(value));`  And it *only* logs `[object Object]`?  *Not* `"evt.target = "`?  That seems unlikely.

Comment: @David it the console log for the 2 states was undefined as my object does not have property .name now just logging value instead of value.name results in both state values logging "evt target = " [object Object]

Comment: This is just going in circles.  Can you perhaps provide a runnable [mcve] which *demonstrates* the problem?

Comment: this function here `    const handleFirstChange = (value) => {
        console.log("evt.target = ",(value));
        setFirstActivity(value);
    }` logs evt target =  [object Object

Comment: @David I cannot exactly as the data I am using is from my API I can edit the question to add screenshots of all the console logs?

Comment: You don't have to use sensitive data, you can use mock data in a [mcve].  What matters is demonstrating the *functionality*, not the specific data.

Comment: @David ok will try produce a runnable

Comment: @David I have updated the question using mock data is that helpful?

Comment: No.  Can you [create a runnable snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338537/328193) which *demonstrates* the problem?  (Or, failing that, at least in an off-site environment like Code Sandbox?)

Comment: @David I am not exactly sure how I could produce a runnable version of this code as this is a full stack application with around 50+ components meaning I would need to include a router to get to this page no?

Comment: the main issue that is occurring seems to be that I cannot figure out why the data is in the form of object Object when it is selected from the menu as well as the states being undefined when I click the button. When I seem to set the states inside my handleFisrtChange and handleSecondChange

Comment: If the problem is in any of those other 50+ components then you're going to want to narrow it down a bit anyway.  The "minimal" part of a [mcve] is important.  If you haven't narrowed down the problem at all then you still have some debugging to do.

Comment: @David I have narrowed down the problem it ocurring inside the 2 components provided as the application was working as expected before trying to get the selected values from my Menu component inside my Replay component

Comment: @David I had been working on the issue from this question I had previously asked and trying to implement the answer I received from the question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75165923/how-to-get-the-value-of-my-select-menu-inside-another-component-from-the-compon

Comment: Then now is a good time for you to take those two components and create a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem.  Anything they depend on (e.g. `GlobalContext`) can be mocked with known working data/functionality.  Once you have that [mcve] which demonstrates the problem, it'll be easier to debug and identify the problem.

Comment: @David are you able to work from this: https://codesandbox.io/s/javascript-forked-2jk6rp?file=/App.js

Comment: @David try: https://codesandbox.io/s/javascript-forked-6ko8k9?file=/Menu.js
working now i believe

Answer (score 0):

First Problem:

`alert` doesn't take multiple arguments.  This is one of the many reasons not to use it for debugging.  Use `console.log` instead:

```
console.log("values select are: ", firstActivity, secondActivity);
```

Second Problem:

You're passing the value to your change handler function(s):

```
props.onChange(evt.target.value);
```

A value which you just logged as a plain value and observed that it's just a number:

```
console.log("evt.target.value = ", evt.target.value);
```

Then in that handler function you again observe that the value passed to it is just a number (or at least a numeric string):

```
console.log("evt.target = ",(value));
```

Then what do you try to do with that value?  This:

```
setFirstActivity(value.name);
```

Why do you expect it to have a `name` property?  Where did that property come from?  It's just a plain value.  Use the value:

```
setFirstActivity(value);
```

[Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-tdd-tfkqct?file=/src/Replay.js)

Comment: from the example I removed the name property as that was from my API data. So the issue is I plan to use the selected values inside Menu inside my Replay component but could not get the values to be stored inside a state properly inside Replay component?

Comment: @taat: Referencing the example linked above, created from copying/pasting the code in the question (and only removing the `useContext` part, which wasn't being used anyway), the state updates are clearly and demonstrably working as expected when using `value` instead of `value.name`.  What isn't working for you?

Comment: but when used with my data I get object Object which I cannot figure out why providing a sample of one piece of my activity data here:


{positions: Array(369), name: 'Lunch Run', activityType: 'Run'}

Comment: @taat: What in the example provided is producing the output `[object Object]`?  When I select options from the drop-down menus and click the button, everything works as expected.  Please clarify how you are seeing this other output?

Comment: yes the value seems to be an object and I cannot figure out exactly what that object property is I have tried like mentioned .name but it appears it doesn't have that property and applying JSON.stringify to the object doesn't make it any different

Comment: inside Replay component with the API data which is present in  the context it appears that the console.log inside handleFirstChange produces `[object Object]`

Comment: @taat: Not in the example you've provided it isn't.  The code shown, when given the corrections specified here, demonstrably works as expected.  I don't doubt that you may have *some other problem(s)* in your application.  But clearly those other problems aren't what/where you think they are.  I don't see how anybody here can help with a problem that the code you've provided *doesn't have*.

Comment: could it be possibly to do with the structure of my data objects

Comment: @taat: It could, yes.  Or it could have something to do with the code you've written which uses that data.  Or it could be entirely unrelated.  It could be *anything* in the code/data-structures that *nobody here can see*.

Comment: @taat: *As a guess*, seeing the output `[object Object]` *usually* means that the code is trying to treat an object as a string.  So if that's the output you're seeing, then the best advice would be to not try to treat an object as a string.